Derivative of trace of kronecker multiplied with another matrix
I have the expression
$$
f(\mathbf{X}) = \text{tr}(\mathbf{G} (\mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{X}))
$$
and I am looking for the derivative with respect to $\mathbf{X}$.
Some additional information: $\mathbf X, \mathbf A$ are $n\times n$ matrices, $\mathbf{G}$ is a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix and all the matrices are real-valued. I can obtain a solution in terms of the elements of the matrices $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{A}$, but my question is, is there a nice way of obtaining the gradient in matrix notation?
I tried a small example, assuming $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf X$ are $2\times 2$ matrices, along with $\mathbf G$ being a $4\times 4$ matrix. I can obtain the function in terms of $x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{21}$, and $x_{22}$, then taking the derivative with respect to each variables is not a problem. Additionally, I thought the chain rule would work here, but I do not obtain the correct expression when doing so.

$
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\oo{\big[\o\big]}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big[#1\big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\size#1{\op{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\mb#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\LR{#1}}}
$At first glance, the Frobenius product
is just a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B^*:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
}$$
but it has many properties which make it indispensable
for doing Matrix Calculus.
For the current problem, we'll need the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
W:A \,+\, X:B &+\; Y:C \,+\, Z:D = \mb{W&X\\\hline Y&Z} : \mb{A&B\\\hline C&D} \\
\LR{W:A}\LR{X:B} &= \LR{W\k X}:\LR{A\k B} \\
}$$
The Kronecker product has some nice properties of its own
$$\eqalign{
\LR{A^T\k B^T} &= \LR{A\k B}^T \\
\LR{W\k X}^T\LR{A\k B} &= \LR{W^TA}\k\LR{X^TB} \\
}$$
Assume the following matrix dimensions
$$\eqalign{
q,p &= \size{A}, \qq m,n=\size{X}, \qq pn,qm=\size{G} \\
p,p &= \size{I_p} \qq\{{\sf identity\ matrix}\} \qq pm,pn=\size{B} \\
}$$
and write the objective function using the above notation
$$\eqalign{
f
 &= G^T:\LR{AI_p\k I_mX} \\
 &= G^T:\LR{A\k I_m}\LR{I_p\k X} \\
 &= \LR{A\k I_m}^TG^T:\LR{I_p\k X} \\
 &\equiv B:\LR{I_p\k X} \\
}$$
In the last line, notice that the term in parentheses is a $\sf Block\ Diagonal$ matrix.
There are a total of $p\times p$ blocks, each of which is $X$-shaped,
but the off-diagonal blocks are all zero.
Applying the same partitioning to the $B$ matrix yields the desired gradient
$$\small\eqalign{
B &= \mb{
\c{B_{11}} & B_{12} & \ldots & B_{1p} \\\hline
B_{21} & \c{B_{22}} & \ldots & B_{2p} \\\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \c\ddots & \vdots \\\hline
B_{p1} & B_{p2} & \ldots & \c{B_{pp}} \\
}
 \qiq f = \c{\sum_{k=\o}^p B_{kk}}:X 
 \qiq \grad fX &= \sum_{k=\o}^p B_{kk} 
\\\\
}$$
An equivalent (but more intimidating) formula is
$$\eqalign{
\grad fX
 &= \sum_{k=\o}^p \LR{e_k\k I_m}^T\LR{A\k I_m}^TG^T\LR{e_k\k I_n}
}$$
where $e_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ column of $I_p$

You can also easily rewrite this looking at the trace as a Hilbert-Schmidt inner product, $\langle A,B\rangle\equiv \operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger B)$. Assuming real matrices:
$$f(X)=\langle G^T,A\otimes X\rangle =
\langle (A^T\otimes I) G^T,I\otimes X\rangle
= \langle \operatorname{tr}_1[(A^T\otimes I)G^T],X\rangle,$$
where in the last step I used the partial trace to isolate $X$. This step is simply a "partial" version of the general observation that the trace amounts in this notation to an inner product with the identity: $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\langle I,A\rangle$.
At this point you simply have an expression of the form $\langle B,X\rangle$ to compute the gradient of. And this is made particularly easy observing the this inner product also can be seen as the regular Euclidean inner product of the vectorized matrices:
$$\langle B, X\rangle= \sum_{ij} B_{ij} X_{ij} \equiv\langle  \operatorname{vec}(B),\operatorname{vec}(X)\rangle.$$
Thus
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij} }\langle B,X\rangle = B_{ij},
\quad\text{ that is, }
\quad\nabla_X \langle B,X\rangle = B.$$
We thus conclude that
$$\nabla_X f(X) = \operatorname{tr}_1[(A^T\otimes I)G^T].$$
This expression is of course equivalent to the one in the other answer if you explicitly write down the partial trace with respect to an orthonormal basis for the first space.

Let $A$ be $m\times m$ and $X$ be $n\times n$ (we do not assume that $m=n$). Partition $G$ into $m^2$ sub-blocks, each of size $n\times n$. Denote the $(k,l)$-th sub-block by $G^{(kl)}$. Then
\begin{align}
f(X)
&= \text{tr}(G(A\otimes X))\tag{1}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m\text{tr}\left(\big(G(A\otimes X)\big)^{(kk)}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m\text{tr}\left(\sum_{l=1}^m G^{(kl)}(A\otimes X)^{(lk)}\right)\\
&= \sum_j\text{tr}\left(\sum_i G^{(kl)}(a_{lk}X)\right)\\
&= \text{tr}\left(\left(\sum_{k,l} a_{lk}G^{(kl)}\right)X\right)\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}
=\left(\sum_{k,l} a_{lk}G^{(kl)}\right)^T.\tag{3}
$$
Although the definition of $f$ in $(1)$ involves multiplication of two $mn\times mn$ matrices $G$ and $A\otimes X$, expressions $(2)$ and $(3)$ show that only a weighted sum of $n\times n$ sub-blocks of $G$ is actually involved.

You're missing the $(i,j)$ indices on the RHS of $(3);$

@greg I am not. The bracket notations on the two sides of $(3)$ are different. What inside the pair of brackets on the LHS is the $(i,j)$-th element of an unnamed matrix. What inside the pair of brackets on the RHS is already a matrix. Brackets are only used because I need to take the transpose of an unnamed matrix. One may write the RHS as $\left(\sum_{k,l} a_{lk}G^{(kl)}{ji}\right){i,j\in{1,2,\ldots,n}}$ to keep the notations on the two sides consistent, but that is unnecessary.

This is how you'd do it using tensor diagrams:

Here the triangle tensor encodes "flattening" of two dimensions, so the kronecker product $A\otimes X$ is simply the outer product of A and X flattened on both sides.
Sadly the resulting diagram doesn't have a natural representation in "classical notation".
But you can easily write it in sum notation as $o_{jl} = \sum_{ik} G_{ijkl} A_{ik}$.
Alternatively, if we consider $G$ an order-4 tensor, $G_{ijkl}$ where $i$ and $j$ are on the left and $k$ and $l$ are on the right, the diagram shows we can flatten $(i,k)$ and $(j,l)$ to get a simple formula:

res = $G' \text{vec}(A)$.
